# Which variable controls the color of 'transient-mark-mode'?

Tags: emacs

The color of the transient mark is a slight shade of grey, barely visible. Which variable sets that color?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `M-x customize-face region`

Comment: The value is `gtk_selection_bg_color`. Let's fix it in gtk then.

Comment: @Reactormonk But, in Ubuntu, in other windows (like Firefox), the selection bg is not barely visible; it's an orange-brown color. So, it might be already correctly configured in GTK to be a better visible color, but Emacs doesn't get it... See also [Highlighting a region in emacs is invisible because region color equals window color](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/emacs24/+bug/1628707)